# MvxAutoCompleTextView loses binding on PatialText

Tags: c#, android, mono, mvvmcross

I am using an MvxAutoCompleTextView and I've confirmed that the ItemsSource and the SelectedObject are bound correctly and working (I added some code that when the widget gets focus, it executes the ShowDropDown and sure enough the expected items are there).

The problem starts when I start typing to filter down the list. At the first go, the ItemsSource gets filtered correctly. But I noticed that sometimes it filters based on only some of the typed characters. Sometimes it is the first character, sometimes it is the first 2. Basically a hit and miss thing. Below is a sample stack trace...

`01-09 13:33:37.145 D/AbsListView( 3098): onDetachedFromWindow
[0:] 
01-09 13:33:37.185 D/AbsListView( 3098): Get MotionRecognitionManager
mvx:Diagnostic:116.54 Wait starting for ac
01-09 13:33:37.395 I/mono-stdout( 3098): mvx:Diagnostic:116.54 Wait starting for ac
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic:116.54 Wait starting for ac
[0:] 
mvx:Diagnostic:116.82 Wait finished with 772 items for ac
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic:116.82 Wait finished with 772 items for ac
01-09 13:33:37.745 I/mono-stdout( 3098): mvx:Diagnostic:116.82 Wait finished with 772 items for ac
[0:] 
mvx:Diagnostic:117.03 Wait starting for ac
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic:117.03 Wait starting for ac
01-09 13:33:37.805 I/mono-stdout( 3098): mvx:Diagnostic:117.03 Wait starting for ac
01-09 13:33:38.025 D/AbsListView( 3098): onDetachedFromWindow
01-09 13:33:38.095 D/AbsListView( 3098): Get MotionRecognitionManager`

You might notice the 'Wait starting for ac' when I typed acc.

I also notice that as soon as it filters the first time and you add additional text to further filter down the list, the setter of the property bound to PartialText never gets called. Same thing happens when you backspace.

`<MvxAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoComplete"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/template_autocomplete"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Hazards; PartialText SearchTerm; SelectedObject SelectedHazard"
    style="@style/edit_text.medium.fill" />`

Here's the property that's bound to PartialText:

`private string _searchTerm;
        public string SearchTerm
        {
            get { return _searchTerm; }
            set 
            { 
                _searchTerm = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchTerm);
                Filter();
            }
        }`

What am I doing wrong? Have I missed something?

I hope I explained it clearly. Thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Jaime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android's AutoCompleteTextView is a real PITA. The likely reason you are seeing that "the setter of the property bound to PartialText never gets called." is because the control is still waiting for the ItemsSource to be updated from a previous change.

I had the same issue and answered it here, [PartialTextChanged stops firing on MvxAutoCompleteTextView after Item selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543931/partialtextchanged-stops-firing-on-mvxautocompletetextview-after-item-selection). Basically every change to the PartialText **must** result in a change to ItemsSource.

You will know it has stopped working when you see "mvx:Diagnostic: Wait starting for YOURPARTIALTEXT" but no matching "mvx:Diagnostic:116.82 Wait finished..."

WRT your search sometimes being one character out I suggest adding Debug.WriteLine to the setter of SearchTerm and Debug.WriteLine around the search call in Filter. Somewhere you will be updating and responding to SearchTerm changes at the wrong time.

p.s. you are probably already doing this but just in case, do not use the VS Output Window to watch the debug output. Use the Android Device Log window and filter by "stdout"

Pat

Comment: Thanks a lot Pat! It was your related answer that pointed me in the right direction. I had to call the NotifyDataSetChanged on the adapter after text has changed.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. NotifyDataSetChanged should be getting called when you update the ItemsSource

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the bindings are not set because of the linker? In that case you could add it to your LinkerPleaseInclude.cs file like this:

```
public void Include(MvxAutoCompleteTextView text)
        {
            text.TextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = "" + text.Text;
            text.PartialTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = "" + text.Text;
            text.SelectedObjectChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = "" + text.Text;
        }
```